# Values are shown on Double click of an variable in chrome debugger

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

Values are shown on Double click of an variable in chrome debugger! but not on hover..
Can anyone explain why the values are not shown on hover instead on double click?

[values not shown on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhpad.png)

[Values shown on double click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWb8B.png)